# Using values defined in Liquibase property file inside CDATA tag

Tags: maven, liquibase

Unfortunately we don't use Liquibase built-in tags at work and it's already too late to fix the existing changesets. Has anyone tried to pass parameters to queries wrapped in **CDATA** tag without modifying the Liquibase maven plugin? However, Adding a new maven build plugin is ok.

```
<changeSet id="XXXXX" author="Mehrad">    
    <sql>
    <![CDATA[
        DO SOMETHING USING THE PARAMETER.. 
    ]]>
    </sql>

    <rollback><sql><![CDATA[ do something else ]]></sql></rollback>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquibase support [changelog paramters](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html) which I think is what you are looking for. You should be able to use then in CDATA blocks, especially with the later (3.2.2+) versions of Liquibase.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, worked like a charm on version 2.0.3. I wasn't expecting changelog params to work outside of built-in attributes.